# Using aws cdk to create elasticbeanstalk instance

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk

I am using following code to create an instance of elasticbeanstalk, however, when I try to deploy, it throws `No application with name pythonService is found`

```
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import ebs = require('@aws-cdk/aws-elasticbeanstalk');

export class DevOpsStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const webAppName: string = 'pythonService';

    const webApp = new ebs.CfnApplication(this, webAppName);

    const pythonServiceS3BucketName : string = 'my-bucket-name'
    const pythonServiceArchiveName : string = 'my-awesome-app.zip'
    const webAppVersion = new ebs.CfnApplicationVersion(this, 'pythonServiceVer', {
      applicationName: webAppName,
      sourceBundle: {
        s3Bucket: pythonServiceS3BucketName,
        s3Key: pythonServiceArchiveName
      }
    });

    const options: ebs.CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty[] = [{
      namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc',
      optionName: 'VPCId',
      value: 'a-vpc-id'
    }, {
      namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc',
      optionName: 'Subnets',
      value: 'a-subnet-id'
    }];

    const webAppEnv = new ebs.CfnEnvironment(this, 'pythonServiceEnv', {
      applicationName: webAppName,
      solutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.2 running Python 3.6',
      optionSettings: options
    });
  }
}
```

I believe this is happening because it tries to deploy `CfnApplicationVersion` before creating `CfnApplication`.

```
DevOpsStack: creating CloudFormation changeset...
 0/5 | 8:33:48 PM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application        | pythonService
 0/5 | 8:33:48 PM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CDK::Metadata                        | CDKMetadata
 0/5 | 8:33:48 PM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment        | pythonServiceEnv
 0/5 | 8:33:48 PM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion | pythonServiceVer
 0/5 | 8:33:48 PM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application        | pythonService Resource creation Initiated
 1/5 | 8:33:48 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion | pythonServiceVer No Application named 'pythonService' found. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: cd1a9f2b-a3fc-450a-9c34-fec13132f613)
```

Also, the cloudformation template it generates, doesn't has `!Ref` before application:

```
Resources:
  pythonService:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: DevOpsStack/pythonService
  pythonServiceVer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      **ApplicationName: pythonService**
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket: ...
        S3Key: ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually build the dependency tree as there are no references between CfnApplication and CfnApplicationVersion. So add CfnApplication as dependency to ensure it is deployed before CfnApplicationVersion:

`webAppVersion.addDependsOn(webApp);`

Comment: not working :/ even though i can see that call to create resources are in correct order and just to make sure that application is being created with correct name, i commented out everything but the `webApp` and can confirm that the created ebs application does get the name `pythonService`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and found the `addDependsOn` suggestion from  [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57873605/6894670) to work well.

However, this just adding this fix will deploy the Sample Application because your environment does not reference a particular version. In addition to the `dependsOn` fix, I believe you need to add versionLabel`to your`webAppEnv`:

```js
    const webAppEnv = new ebs.CfnEnvironment(this, 'pythonServiceEnv', {
      applicationName: webAppName,
      solutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.2 running Python 3.6',
      optionSettings: options,
      versionLabel webAppVersion.ref
    });
```